# c# windows form- How I am click span in "Enter a Phone Number" button?

Tags: c#, html, c#-4.0, webbrowser-control, c#-5.0

How I am click "Enter a phone number" I am already using my code. This code working other all section but in the section not working.

```
<span class="uiButtonText">Enter a phone number >/span>
```

see my code

```
{
    HtmlElementCollection elc = this.webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("span");
    foreach (HtmlElement el in elc)
    {
        if (el.GetAttribute("type").Equals("Enter a phone number"))
        {
            el.InvokeMember("Click");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
el.GetAttribute("type")
```

The text is not an attribute.  You want the inner text of the HtmlElement:

```
if(el.InnerText == "Enter a phone number")
```